Is "natural person" an idiomatic way to describe someone who's the opposite of pretentious?
Often in Spanish, we use the adjective "natural" to describe someone who looks natural (not much makeup or expensive clothes) or someone who is the opposite of pretentious. Would you use "natural" to express any of these meanings or would you rather use other adjectives?
To give context, I'll write a sentence which you can modify to make it more idiomatic:

A. Anna is modest and sincere. She is a natural person.
B. There are many pretentious people in this business. I´d rather work with more natural folks.

What would you write instead of natural?

I'd use it by itself: Anna is modest and sincere. She is natural. There are many pretentious poeple in this business. I´d rather work with more natural folks. [Or, those more natural.]

Oh ok. That´s interesting. Would you say this use is idiomatic across age groups and regions where you live?

Yes I would. It's only natural.

@YosefBaskin I think it's okay with sufficient context, but it can mean too many different things on its own.

A hairdresser I hadn't been to before once said to me "You're a very natural lady, aren't you?", presumably referring to the fact that I don't dye my hair.

All your comments are very helpful. I can see how a word can not only express different meanings on its own in different contexts but also how their meanings might be hindering each other like in the legal sphere compared to the hairdressing one where it´s easily understood. To express the idea of non-artificiality or modesty in terms of behavior, we might need further clarification or the use of other words as aid for this particular meaning.

It wouldn't be clear what you meant by "natural".
A person who's authentic is genuine and trustworthy.
Down-to-earth emphasizes clearheadedness and practicality, but also implies sincerity.

Authentic and down-to-earth are pretty good for what I´m trying to express. You didn´t use the word "natural" in any of those constructions, so I would imagine that its meaning is nowhere close to what it means in Spanish.  I appreciate it.

@MarceloMartel It could mean what you intend - people would understand what you intend from context and nobody would point and laugh at the ELL.  It's not a typical use case though.  "Natural person" in general isn't really used in common language, though you might be able to find cases here and there using it to mean half a dozen different things.

@JasonPatterson Yes, great addition.

Typical of languages. While there is room for applicabilty, it´s not widely used at least for now. Thanks a lot.

I like 'sincere' as well as 'genuine'. I am not sure 'authentic' is clear enough. I agree that 'natural' is vague and it's meaning without more context could be misinterpreted.

"Natural person" in English is most often used as a comparison against legal persons, such as corporations in some circumstances.
For the situation you describe, I would most likely go with "natural-looking" in order to emphasize the person's non-artificial appearance.

Would you say that the use of "natural" is basically found in various other contexts with the exception of describing personality traits?

@MarceloMartel "Natural" is used commonly as a regular adjective indicating not fake/not artificial/not manufactured. However, the phrase "natural person" is used as a set phrase in legal contexts, and is not commonly used otherwise. As such, someone familiar with the legal phrase will likely read it as such, rather than think of it as a noun plus regular adjective.

Alright. The meaning that "natural person" conveys is deeply rooted in people´s heads, giving way to other terms to express the idea of no artificiality and so on. Thanks a lot.

I partly agree with this answer - "natural-looking" ought to mean minimal make-up, but more often than not these days it means more than that. Natural-looking could mean someone is not surgically enhanced. "The natural look" is a veiled insult meaning someone has failed to groom themselves to the expected standard, such as women with hairy legs and armpits. Further, we borrow the French "au natural" to mean someone has not done any grooming whatsoever.

@Astralbee Uh... usually "au naturel" is a euphemism for "totally naked".

'Natural person' does not have the same idiomatic meaning you describe in English. We do say "act naturally" as an advisory to someone to be themselves and not to put on a pretence. We also say that someone "is a natural" when they are naturally talented at a particular thing, so to use the phrase 'natural person' would be a bad idea as it would more likely be mistaken for these idioms.
I would suggest you use either the word 'modest' or 'unpretentious'.
'Modest' has a broad meaning - describing someone as modest can mean they do not have an over-inflated view of their abilities or achievements. But you can also say, for example, that a person is modest in their dress, or presents themselves modestly to mean that they do not go for showy styles that draw attention to themselves.
Likewise, 'unpretentious' has a broad meaning that can mean a person who does not attempt to impress others with their outward appearance or who does not have an inflated view of their own importance or talent. But you can also say they dress or present themselves pretentiously to specifically refer to their dress and grooming.

Re: "We do say 'act naturally' as an advisory to someone to be themselves and not to put on a pretence": There may be a regional difference here; in the US we generally say "act natural" (with the same meaning).

Naturally beautiful and good nature.

Would you use "natural" to express any of these meanings or would you rather use other adjectives?

I.Two phrases to describe beauty without makeup:.
In English, we can use either of these phrases to express beauty without makeup :- "naturally beautiful" and "barefaced".
Natural beauty means precisely what it sounds like: beauty in its natural and original form. The term can be applied to a something that has come from the natural world, such as a landscape or a person. Of course, beauty is highly subjective.

Ref. urbandictionary.com.
1.naturally beautiful.
Where some one is beautiful or "Good Looking/Hot" naturally, being no added make up or additions.
Did you see Saundra, she is so naturally beautiful!
2.barefaced.
adjective (WITHOUT MAKEUP).
not wearing any makeup (= colored substances used on your face to improve or change your appearance):
She still looks like a teenager when she's barefaced and ponytailed.
I prefer a barefaced, natural look.

II. Words describing a person's character..

A. Anna is modest and sincere. She is a natural person.
B. There are many pretentious people in this business. I´d rather work with more natural folks.

A. Anna is modest and sincere. She is  good natured.
B. There are many pretentious people in this business. I´d rather work with good natured folks.

Ref. Collins dictionary
good nature..
in American English
a pleasant, agreeable, or kindly disposition; amiability; geniality.

Other words.

1.sincere.
adjective.
(of a person, feelings, or behaviour) not pretending or lying; honest:
a sincere apology.
He seems so sincere.
2..straightforward adjective (HONEST).
(of a person) honest and not likely to hide their opinions:
Roz is straightforward and lets you know what she's thinking.
3..forthright.
adjective.
(too) honest or direct in behaviour or speech:
4.benevolent
adjective.
kind and helpful:
He was a benevolent old man and wouldn't hurt a fly.
5.warm-hearted.
adjective.
kind and loving:
She's a good, warm-hearted woman.
6.unselfish.
adjective.
An unselfish person thinks about what is good for other people, not just about their own advantage.


Why the down vote? These meanings are from dictionary. What OP asked is there in dictionary.

Really good examples. I have a better idea now of what I can use in each situation. I can also see that in Spanish with emphazise more the genuineness in appearance and character when we use "natural" rather than the kidness or unselfishness.

The word that you are looking for is unassuming.
Authentic and genuine suggested by others also work if you want to emphasize the opposite of acting in a fake manner. In contrast, unassuming emphasizes that you do not seek to project authority or importance or to attract attention.

In English, "natural person" is used almost entirely in a legal context as @SoronelHaetir said.
What you want is "genuine".  It's more common to use that by itself though, not with "person".  Modifying your example:
"There are many pretentious people in this business. I´d rather work with someone more genuine."

Yes, I agree.  The meaning I have in mind is better expressed by this one, which we also use in Spanish "genuino".
